# Lighting candles rather than oil-lamps on Diwâlî a scripturally prescribed practise?

Tags: scripture, practice, tradition, festivals

Does any scriptures mention use of candles on the night of Diwâlî ?

Lighting a seasame oil or ghee based dîyâ is considered auspicious.
However, these days it's more common for people to light up candles rather than an oil-lamp (dîyâ) on the night of Diwâlî. Not to forget the artificial lightings too.

So, does scriptures mention anything about candles and the significance of lighting them, either on Diwâlî or in any other setting in general?

More broadly, does candles even find a mention in any canonical scriptures?

Comment: Interesting Q. From Skanda Purana, Kartikamasa Mahatmya, Vaishnava Khanda, they don’t mention candles but deepaka without mentioning the word ‘oil deepaka’ or whatever. Purana is supposed to have been written 5000 years ago. As per [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Candle), the earliest candles were 200 BC in China and before they’ve found evidence for the use of oil lamps. Hence we take deepak to mean diyas only. Technically Deepak means light only so I guess any light should do? They’re mainly concerned with illumination. Light is from fire electricity is also fire so is wax lit up

Comment: Well, we call the divine of the form: *jyotirûpam*, @Archit, and thus the significance of lighting a lamp. The ghee or seasame oil being specifically used as fuel, might have some significance too. However, any light should do? I don't think so.  I might be wrong. IMO, A deepak specifically lit with cow ghee or some specific oil are generally recommended. Thus any random lighting product seems a bit far streching.